# nohup - no such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, nohup

I'm trying to execute the following command on my CentOS 6.3 x64 server:

```
nohup "/usr/local/bin/php -v"
```

The result is:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command `/usr/local/bin/php -v': No such file or directory
```

This works on CentOS 5 no problem. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's happening because you don't have a file named `/usr/local/bin/php -v`. Since you put it in quotes, the entire string is being treated as the argument.

Try removing the quotes.

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/php -v
```

Comment: yes in my case it was not the usual cron/path but transferring a command from daemon (which had the quotes around multiple args), and the nohup command, which did not need that